# Output or input in prolog

Tags: prolog

I just "learned" Prolog and I don't really understand what is the input and what is the output in a function.

For instance

```
concatenate([X|L1], L2, [X|L3]) = concatenate (L1,L2,L3).
concatenate([],L,L).
```

what does it mean?

```
If I write 
?- concatenate(X,[2,Y],[1,1,1,2,3])
```

it returns

```
X=[1,1,1],
Y=3.
```

So it means that 3rd param is the concatenation of 1st and 2d but how can we know this by reading the declaration of the function?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just supplementing two already excellent answers...

In Prolog, you don't think of things as "functions" with parameter inputs and outputs (although they do behave that way), but rather as "predicates" that define rules and which will attempt instantiate any variable parameters (uninstantiated variables) in such a way as to make the rule be true. This process may result in no solutions, one solution, or many solutions, and you will get them all. Not all predicates provide this "full functionality" for every combination of uninstantiated variables, or if too many variables are uninstantiated, it becomes logically impractical to provide solutions. What dictates the behavior of the parameters under any of these circumstances, and whether the predicate has any solutions, is the logic of the predicate, not any formal declaration of inputs or outputs.

Let's take the given `concatenate` as an example (NOTE I am using GNU Prolog for these). What the predicate `concatenate(L1, L2, L3)` means is that "L1 concatenated with L2 (in that order) gives L3", which is more general than saying "given L1 and L2, provide their concatenation in L3", which implies specific inputs and outputs.

So if I enter:

```
concatenate( [1,2], [3,4], L3 ).
```

I get:

```
L3 = [1,2,3,4]

(1 ms) yes
| ?-
```

Which means prolog found one solution to the predicate with the shown instantiation of `L3`. I could also enter this:

```
concatenate( L1, [3,4], [1,2,3,4] ).
```

And I would get:

```
L1 = [1,2]

(1 ms) yes
| ?-
```

Which means prolog found one solution to the predicate with the shown instantiation of `L1`. Similarly if I entered `concatenate( [1,2], L2, [1,2,3,4] )` I'd get one solution: `L2 = [3,4]`.

Let's try something more interesting:

```
concatenate( L1, L2, [1,2,3,4] ).
```

Prolog will find solutions for this but I've provided two uninstantiated variables. So the solutions will involve possibilities for these:

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4]
L2 = [] ? ;

L1 = [1,2,3]
L2 = [4] ? ;

L1 = [1,2]
L2 = [3,4] ? ;

L1 = [1]
L2 = [2,3,4] ? ;

L1 = []
L1 = [1,2,3,4] ? ;

(1 ms) yes
| ?-
```

Now let's try this:

```
concatenate( [1,2], L2, L3 ).
```

I get:

```
L3 = [1,2|L2]

| ?-
```

In this case, the possibilities for `L2` and, therefore, `L3` are unbounded, so prolog is showing a general solution.

In your example, `concatenate( X, [2,Y], [1,1,1,2,3] )` the same idea applies. Prolog will attempt to find instantiations of `X` and `Y` that satisfy the condition that "X concatenated with [2,Y] gives [1,1,1,2,3]", and [2,Y] is a list with first element `2` and second element `Y`. In this case, there is only one solution as you show.

As a variation on this theme, using the list concepts that @DrH describes, if you did:

```
concatenate( X, [2|Y], [1,1,1,2,3] ).
```

You would get `X = [1,1,1]` and `Y = [3]`. Note that if you did this:

```
concatenate( X, [2,Y], [1,1,1,2,3,4] ).
```

You get 'no' (no solution) because `Y` is shown here as an atom, not a list (because of the comma syntax). In other words, there's no two element list that looks like `[2,Y]` which, when concatenated with any possibility for `X` will yield `[1,1,1,2,3,4]`. But if you did this:

```
concatenate( X, [2|Y], [1,1,1,2,3,4] ).
```

You would get `X = [1,1,1]` and `Y = [3,4]` because now I show the uninstantiated `Y` as a tail of a list, which is itself a list, not just an atom (using the `|` syntax).

As @WillNess points out, the documentation for a given predicate will tell you want to expect for the behavior of the predicate if you leave certain variables uninstantiated. A well-written prolog predicate will more likely "do what you expect or want" than one that is not as well-written or is more restrictive. That doesn't make a more restricted predicate "bad" as it might serve a very useful purpose. It just won't be as useful. When writing your own prolog predicate, you take these things in to consideration.

Prolog is like the game of Go: a few simple rules but many interesting possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

there should be a comment with descriptions for each argument of a predicate what is expected of them: to be preset (so can be used as input), to be free (not yet set, so used for output), or no preference (so can be both).

Check out the [documentation for SWI Prolog - 4.1 Notation of Predicate Descriptions](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=preddesc). They use

- `+` for fully instantiated argument
- `-` argument must be unbound, will be used for output
- `?` partially instantiated argument of correct type (note that an uninstantiated variable is a partial term for any type).

and few other more advanced options.

Sometimes with the source code as simple as in your example, it can be considered self-evident which is which.

Answer (score 1):

```
concatenate([X|L1], L2, [X|L3]) :-
    concatenate(L1, L2, L3).
```

First of all, lists in Prolog consist of a head (here `X`) and a tail (the rest of the lists, here `L1` and `L3`). So this predicate says there is a list, its first element being `X`, if you concatenate it with `L2`, you'll get a list whose first element is also `X` while its tail is some `L3`. In order for this predicate to be true, it's also necessary that the predicate `concatenate(L1, L2, L3)` does not fail, that is, the rest of the first list can be concatenated with the second list, and they will result in the third one.

As arguments can be either be input or output variables, you can call this predicate with either unknown variables, or if you have three lists, you can check if one of them can be created by concatenating the other two.

The second predicate `concatenate([], L, L)` says if the first list is empty, the result of the concatenation is the second list.

Let `L1` be `[1, 2, 3]` and `L2` be `[4, 5, 6]`. Let's call our predicate and see what happens inside:

```
concatenate(L1, L2, L3).
concatenate([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], L3).    // First predicate can be matched
concatenate([1 | [2, 3]], [4, 5, 6], [1 | A1]).    // Now [2, 3] is L1 and A1 is the current L3

concatenate([2, 3], [4, 5, 6], A1).    // First predicate can be matched
concatenate([2 | [3]], [4, 5, 6], [2 | A2]).    // Now [3] is L1 and A2 is L3

concatenate([3], [4, 5, 6], A2).    // First predicate can be matched
concatenate([3 | []], [4, 5, 6], [3 | A3]).    // Now [] is L1 and A3 is L3

concatenate([], [4, 5, 6], A3).    // Second predicate can be matched
concatename([], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]).
```

We have an exit condition, a predicate with no body. Now we go backwards (this is called backtracking, going backwards in our search space). Let's substitute the A* variables with the results:

```
concatenate([], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]).

concatenate([3 | []], [4, 5, 6], [3 | [4, 5, 6]]).

concatenate([3], [4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6]).

concatenate([2 | [3]], [4, 5, 6], [2 | [3, 4, 5, 6]]).

concatenate([2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).

concatenate([1 | [2, 3]], [4, 5, 6], [1 | [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]).

concatenate([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]).
```